# EF Core 6 Many to Many nested

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am creating a new Blazor server side application with EF Core 6. I am more used to using database first and Dapper. However I am trying to get more familiar with EF Core and code first approach as requested by the department.

While reviewing the documentation on the changes for EF Core 6 in relation to the many to many relationships, I am stuck on stuck on how to configure the relationships properly for what I call a nested many to many. I believe I have the basic concept of the base 2 tables with many to many but this is a little more complex. I have searched MS and SO but only found some articles that are close but not fitting my situation.

The situation is this, for example 1 table Applications, 1 table Environments and a table Databases. There are an application can have multiple environments at which point the combination of an application(s) / environment(s) can have multiple databases.

Here is how the tables were designed.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[App] (
    [Id]                    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]                  VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Applications] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Env] (
    [Id]            INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          VARCHAR (80)  NOT NULL,
    [Value]         VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Env] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC))

CREATE TABLE [crosswalk].[App_Env] (
    [Id]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AppId] INT NOT NULL,
    [EnvId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_App_Env] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_App_Env_App] FOREIGN KEY ([AppId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[App] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_App_Env_EnvId] FOREIGN KEY ([EnvId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Env] ([Id]))

CREATE TABLE [crosswalk].[App_Env_Db] (
    [Id]        INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AppEnvtId] INT NOT NULL,
    [DbId]      INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_App_Env_Db] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_App_Env_Db_App_Env] FOREIGN KEY ([AppEnvtId]) REFERENCES [crosswalk].[App_Env] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_App_Env_Db] FOREIGN KEY ([DbId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Db] ([Id]))
```

The application is not complete so not able to run it. Was able to come up with one of the configurations but not sure on how to code the rest.

```cs
entity.HasMany(d => d.Envs)
    .WithMany(p => p.Apps)
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
        "AppEnv",
            l => l.HasOne<Env>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("AppId"),
            r => r.HasOne<App>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("EnvId"),
            j =>
            {
                j.HasKey("EnvId", "AppId");
                j.ToTable("Crosswalk.App_Env");
                j.HasIndex(new[] { "EnvId" }, "IX_AppEnv_EnvId");
                j.HasIndex(new[] { "AppId" }, "IX_AppEnv_AppId");
            });
```

The models are as follows:

```cs
[Table("App")]
public partial class App
{
    public App() => Envs = new HashSet<Env>();
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("App")]
    public virtual ICollection<LookupCode> Envs { get; set; }
}

[Table("Env")]
public partial class LookupCode
{
    public LookupCode() => Apps = new HashSet<Apps>();
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Env")]
    public virtual ICollection<App> Apps { get; set; }
}

[Table("Db")]
public partial class Db
{
    public Db() => AppEnvDbs = new HashSet<AppEnvDb>();
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Db")]
    public virtual ICollection<AppEnvDb> AppEnvDbs { get; set; }
}
```

If this is not possible I can go back to creating the DTO's for the link tables and manually adding/creating/deleting the link records.

EDIT: Added missing table definition for Db. Although the DTO model was shown I forgot to include the data table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Db] (
    [Id]         INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DbServerId] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Name]       VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Db] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)    
);
```

Comment: Whoever set your tables up didn't understand normalization. Look at 3rd normal form and handle the transient issue accordingly. Your dependency between the application and the database has to go through the environment. You should have three tables: application, environment, and database. And then your junction table(s) depending on how you want to structure it.

Comment: @GHDevOps The 3rd table (Db for Databases) existed. I forgot to add but did update the post with the table. The class was already there for the table as well as the junction tables.  With the the many to many from application to environment and then the relation from that to the database causing a (many/App to many/Env) to many/Db relationship is being demonstrated in the tables and junction tables shown. However 1) if there is a better way to declare the tables, can you propose it, 2) I am looking for more of a EF Core 6 OnModelCreating configuration to create the tables and relationships.

Comment: If the tables already exist and you're having trouble with the modelbuilder, the easiest approach is to create a console app and scaffold those tables. Compare your builder with the scaffold builder and make the appropriate changes. Then run your migrations. I always attempt to build the tables myself but if I ever run into issues, I'll scaffold and see what I'm doing wrong. Look into reverse engineering: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: @GHDevOps Took your advice and tried both the EF Core Power Tools and the CLI to reverse engineer the database. Then took a mixture of the both as the final set of context and classes. This looks like it will work but I am not sure yet about the many to many relationships yet as the scaffolding of the data context does not seem to have any showing only one to many. In a way I was also trying to have a better understanding of code first approach which is the way the department wants to go. In either case this looks like it will work. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If the scaffold is showing a one-to-many then your model tables are incorrect. Typically a many-to-many uses the one side PK as both the PK and FK in the junction table.  So if many applications can have many environments, your junction table class will look similar to this: public class AppEnv { public int AppId {get;set;}
 [ForeignKey("AppId")]
public virtual Application Application {get;set;} public int EnvironmentId {get;set;}
[ForeginKey("EnvironmentId")]
public virtual Environment Environment {get;set;}

Comment: Inside your Application class add a virtual collection for Environments and inside your Environment class add a virtual collection for Applications

Comment: @GHDevOps When scaffolded using the properties option it did look similar to what you have then I tried the API scaffold and it came up with nothing in the App table, appenv junction table entity.HasOne(d => d.App).WithMany(p => p.AppEnvs).HasForeignKey(d => d.AppId), appenvdb junction table entity.HasOne(d => d.AppEnv).WithMany(p => p.AppEnvDbs).HasForeignKey(d => d.AppEnvtId) and entity.HasOne(d => d.Db).WithMany(p => p.AppEnvDbs).HasForeignKey(d => d.DbId). It may be a pseudo way to do it not sure, will have to test and see. Thanks again.